# simple mysqli NOW() syntax error

Tags: mysqli

sorry, I really don't see it.

I have a mysqli syntax like this:

```
"UPDATE table
SET
used='1',
ip='".mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])."',
when=NOW()
WHERE
uid='x3'"
```

This is my error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>
> ```
> when=NOW()
> WHERE
> uid='x3'' at line 6
> ```

Comment: Always output and analyze the final query, not the PHP code.

Comment: UPDATE table
 SET
 used='1',
 ip='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
 when=NOW()
 WHERE
 uid='x3'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`WHEN` is a reserved word in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).  If you wish to use it as a column name you must surround it in backticks.

In other words, replace

```
when=NOW()
```

with

```
`when`=NOW()
```